# simple web server nort working with arduino wifi shield

Tags: arduino, wifi

I have recently bought an arduino wifi shield(Atmal chip 32UC3A1512-U), which I connected with 
my Arduino Mega ADK R3 board)...It is getting connected to my wifi network, But when I run the
SimpleWebServer Example provided in the library to  on/off the LED is not working. The code  is given below...

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "belkin.E33";      //  your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "abc123cde456";   // your network password
int keyIndex = 0;                 // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);      // initialize serial communication
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);      // set the LED pin mode

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
  Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
   while(true);        // don't continue
   } 

   // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);                   // print the network name (SSID);

    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:    
     status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
     // wait 10 seconds for connection:
     delay(10000);
   } 
  server.begin();                           // start the web server on port 80
  printWifiStatus();        // you're connected now, so print out the        status
}


void loop() {


  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";      // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
     if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
     char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
     Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
     if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

      // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
      // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
      if (currentLine.length() == 0) {  
        // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
        // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:    
        client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        client.println("Content-type:text/html");
        client.println();

        // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
        client.print("Click <a href=\"/H\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 9 on<br>");
        client.print("Click <a href=\"/L\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 9 off<br>");

        // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
        client.println();
        // break out of the while loop:
        break;         
       } 
       else {      // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
         currentLine = "";
       }
     }     
     else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
      currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
    }

    // Check to see if the client request was "GET /H" or "GET /L":
    if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /H")) {
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);               // GET /H turns the LED on
    }
    if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /L")) {
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);                // GET /L turns the LED off
     }
   }
 }
// close the connection:
client.stop();
Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
 Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

 // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
 IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
 Serial.print("IP Address: ");
 Serial.println(ip);

 // print the received signal strength:
 long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
 Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
 Serial.print(rssi);
 Serial.println(" dBm");
// print where to go in a browser:
Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
Serial.println(ip);
 }
```

The result that I am getting in the serial monitor is

```
Attempting to connect to Network named: belkin.E33
SSID: belkin.E33
IP Address: 192.168.2.5
strength (RSSI):-56 dBm
To see this page in action, open a browser to http://192.168.2.5
```

But When I am opening the browser with the specified IP address, It is showing 
    Could not Connect to 192.168.2.5
I have tried this in mozilla and chrome from my ubuntu machine...also tried from some other machines in the same network but with the same result. But when I am pinging to 192.168.2.5 it is pinging...What went wrong??? . My friend adviced to change the firmware...Is it an issue,bcas as told earlier simple examples for establishing the connection are working...Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem after upgrading Arduino IDE to lastest version (v2) from v1.0.8 which is doing fine with the wifi shield tests (client and server).

Going to try the nightly build now and see if it's fixed.

Edit: Yeap, Nightly build solves this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what versions Nuno is referring to because at the time of this writing, the latest release version is 1.0.5 and 1.5.2 is in BETA.  However, I was having the same issue as the asker and solved it by using 1.0.2. For me, the nightlies didn't work.  I assume that a firmware upgrade would also take care of this and then the later version of the IDE would work again.  I haven't confirmed though.